# How to delete the unwanted word that is being generated at the end of the Url in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i have an url of: party_detail_search/search
but the url of [party_detail_search/search?breadcrumbs] and [party_detail_search/search?adycfaf] also redirected to party_detail_search/search with the same web contents...i don't want the duplicate pages, how do i solve this problem

Comment: The behavior seems to be the expected behavior. What do you think is supposed to happens for those URLs?

Comment: What is it suppose to do exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want both the urls:

```
party_detail_search/search?breadcrumbs 
party_detail_search/search?adycfaf
```

to go to same place, then you can define a route in config/routes.rb as follows

```
get 'party_detail_search/search' => 'some_controller#some_action'
```

in 'some_controller' you can define 'some_action'. If you also want the the word after the '?' this is passed as a nil value parameter, named 'breadcrumbs' or 'adycfaf' respectively e.g. `{ 'breadcrumbs' => nil }` the example 'search_parameter' method will extract it from the params hash.

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def some_action
    ..do stuff
  end

private
  def search_parameter
    params.collect{ |key, value| key if value.nil? }.compact.first
  end
end
```